# How to fake the data of 2D laser scanner?

Tags: ros, laser, data

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems that all these kind of sensors are expensive. I wanna understand SLAM by implementing at least "fake" data. I have a point in a virtual environment (OpenGL) represents the position of a robot, so to speak. Now I want to send these "fake" data and visualize them. Is it possible to fake these data? I'm reading a book namely probabilistic robotics which is a very good book, but unfortunately it doesn't cover the practical stuff. Another question, what does the data of 2D laser scanner look like? Any books about this issue ( the communication protocol of 2d laser data)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/70705/how-to-fake-the-data-of-2d-laser-scanner?/) by [CroCo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4955/croco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 155 on 2013-08-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
To simulate the laser data you can do two things.

First, use gazebo simulator there are alot of robots present there for example you can use [erratic robot](http://www.ros.org/wiki/erratic_robot) which is equipped with laser range sensor. So after installing the robot and [simulator_gazebo](http://www.ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo) you can spawn the robot in a gazebo world by this command.

```
roslaunch erratic_description  erratic_laser_wg_world.launch
```

This will bring your gazebo environment with erratic robot in it. It will be publishing topics like /odom /scan /tf which are prerequisites for slam_gmapping. you can run gmapping node and visualize the robot, map and laser scan in [Rviz](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz).

Secondly,you can use the bag files which are recorded data sets of different robots in different environment for example [willow garage data](http://pr.willowgarage.com/data/gmapping/basic_localization_stage.bag). After playing your bag file you can run gmapping and visualize the world in rviz.

2d laser data is distance readings in meters from minimum angle normally 0 degree to maximum angle normally 180 degree. The number of readings depend on the resolution of sensor So resolution of 1 degree means you will have a distance measure after every 1 degree. After running any of the above routine you can do rostopic echo /scan and see what is the distance value and in header information you can see the resolution and range etc. That is how a laser range data looks like in ROS [Laser Scan](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/LaserScan.html).

Edit 1:
you can write your own nodes to publish laser data and odometry data. After running one of the above method you will understand the flow. Gmapping needs /scan /odom /tf just made the nodes which publishes these three data in such a way which is acceptable by gmapping.

---

Originally posted by [Zee-Q](https://answers.ros.org/users/1806/zee-q/) with karma: 235 on 2013-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [CroCo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4955/croco/) on 2013-08-05**:
@Zee-Q, thank you so much. The problem that I'm facing is the compatibility of operating systems, so I'm not able to use ROS, so I'm gonna use another library. I want to simulate SLAM problem, but I didn't find any tutorials about the implementation of it. For example, I have a virtual environment in which there is a point that represents a robot. Now, I can get the x, y and the angle. I want to record the path of moving this point as a first step then I will build obstacles and record everything and based on these data , I will build my SLAM. Based on the book that I'm reading, I need to get the measurements of obstacles and the odometry data. The problem I don't have real sensors, so I need to fake these data but which protocol should I use or in other words which format should I implement my data?